# why is this mod_rewrite rule not working?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

And it's supposed to make `http://www.somedomain.com/?id=3123123` accessible as `http://www.somedomain.com/3123123` but I then get a 500 error. Why is that?

Comment: Your pattern only captures strings that don't start with slashes, but in [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html] examples, all strings start with slashes.

Comment: It's usually fairly easy to see the issue when you use RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to output a log of exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I tried with `http://www.somedomain.com?id=3123123` and that doesn't work either. Is this at all possible? :(

Comment: Thanks, I think I fixed it! *EDIT* Ah nope :( Didn't work.

Comment: I first thought the [L] was the cause. But that's not working either. Argggh!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1   [L]
```